# Are there any advantages in using size_t instead of unsigned int?

Tags: c, string, size-t

For example,

> int len1=strlen(string);
>
> size_t len1 = strlen(string1)

Does using size_t make any difference in the compiler behavior or code run time or difference in memory?
I absolutely know about the difference, which was answered previously in another thread, but I am concerned about RAM behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

`size_t` can store the maximum size an array can get, as it basically can get as big as the addressable memory space.

`unsigned int` is only defined by its minimum range (0 to 65535), but it may be larger. For example you expect it to be 32-bit on a 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is unsigned, whereas `int` is signed. Moreover, on some platform, the `SIZE_MAX` might be greater than `sizeof(int)`. Therefore, to produce portable code, you should use `size_t` (see §7.18.3).

> Data Type: size_t
>
> This is an unsigned integer type used to represent the sizes of objects. The result of the sizeof operator is of this type, and
>   functions such as malloc (see Unconstrained Allocation) and memcpy
>   (see Copying Strings and Arrays) accept arguments of this type to
>   specify object sizes. On systems using the GNU C Library, this will be
>   unsigned int or unsigned long int.

[source](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Important-Data-Types.html)

Comment: So there will be **difference in the memory** of bin file generated(I am facing ram constraints with my MC )? Thanks for the answer!!